# How to find values in SQL Server that contains any numbers and /'s for example 0192/4758/38 or 1293888/9 or 383/4 or 93828/9/2939 - of any length

Tags: sql-server

I want to find values in SQL Server that contains only numbers and /'s for example 0192/4758/38 or 1293888/9 or 383/4 or 93828/9/2939 it can be of any length.

Comment: Use a [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Why not at least attempt to apply the techniques from your [previous and similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72126523/is-there-a-way-to-find-values-that-contain-only-0s-and-a-symbol-of-any-length)

Comment: It is not really the same as the previous question since it can contain any number, not only 0's. I have tried attempts but it did not work :) Raju Ahmed's answer pointed me in the right direction by using the function ISNUMERIC.

Answer (score -1):

Use this following code:

```
SELECT * FROM [YourTableName]
WHERE    ISNUMERIC(REPLACE([YourColumnName], '/', ''))=1 
         AND CHARINDEX('/',[YourColumnName]) > 0
```

Comment: ISNUMERIC is a very flawed function. It will not work in this situation.

Comment: @SMor can you explain how it is flawed & what will be the best option? If it is a flawed function then why Microsoft hasn't removed it yet?